# SQL copy data from 4 columns in a table to 2 columns in new table

Tags: sql

I am curious as to how I can go about copying data from four columns in an old table and placing the data into two columns in a new table. I know that I can use the following for two old columns into one new one. But how do I do it for many columns?

```
INSERT INTO new_table(new_column_xy)
(
    SELECT   old_column_x
    FROM     old_table
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  old_column_y
    FROM    old_table
)
```

Below is what I am trying to accomplish.
[image]

Comment: Please convert your image to text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add the other column in your select:

```
INSERT INTO new_table(employee, employee_id)
SELECT pilot, pilot_id
FROM old_table
UNION ALL
SELECT copilot, copilot_id
FROM old_table
```

Answer (score 1):

```
insert into new_table (employee, employee_id) (
    select pilot as employee
            , pilot_id as employee_id
        from old_table
    union 
    select copilot as employee
            , copilot_id as employee_id
        from old_table
)
```